# How do I set a break point inside of a "require"-d library with node inspector?

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js, node-inspector

I have a library several layers of "require" down from my project, and I'd like to set a breakpoint inside it.

I'm new to node-inspector, and I'm trying to figure out how to find my way into the library and place the breakpoints there. The library isn't listed on the list of scripts, I'm guessing since a require does a dynamic load.

What's the standard way for placing the breakpoint under these conditions? Is the only option placing a breakpoint high in the call chain, and then finding my way down for a second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "debugger" keyword where you want that the debugger stops. It basically sets a breakpoint at that location.

So you could put it in the library you want at the line you want to stop the execution.

I got this from [here](http://technosophos.com/content/nodejs-debugging-built-debugger).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the "standard" way to do it, but this is what I have done in the past:

1. as (one of) the first steps of your application, require the library where you need to set the breakpoints
2. start your application with node --debug-brk app.js
3. open node-inspector and step over until the library has been included
4. refresh node-inspector and you should now see the files for the library in the list
5. set your breakpoints in the library and then resume script execution

Make sense?